# Can calls from multiple BackgroundThreads to MainThread happen at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift

There are probably a lot of better ways to solve this with a completely different approach, but humor me. I'd like to know this exact situation.

Here I have two functions, `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`. They are called from `doEverything()`, and both return a completionBlock that will trigger async.

The goal is to call `everythingDone()` as soon as both these async calls are completed. As I said, there are probably better ways of solving this, but I'd like to know what can happen with this exact logic.

In both completions, I check if both completions have completed, and then call `everythingDone` if it is.

```
func doSomething(completion:((Int)->())?){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        completion?(123)
    }
}
func doSomethingElse(completion:((String)->())?){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        completion?("Test")
    }
}

func doEverything(){
    var values:[Any] = []
    var somethingDone:Bool = false
    var somethingElseDone:Bool = false

    doSomething { (value) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            values.append(value)
            somethingDone = true
            if somethingDone && somethingElseDone{
                self.everythingDone(values: values)
            }
        }
    }
    doSomethingElse { (value) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            values.append(value)
            somethingElseDone = true
            if somethingDone && somethingElseDone{
                self.everythingDone(values: values)
            }
        }
    }
}

func everythingDone(values:[Any]){
    print("Everything done: ", values)
}
```

Can `everythingDone` ever happen twice? Is there a slight possibility that the order of events can cause this:

1. DoSomething-completion sets `somethingDone=true`
2. DoSomethingElse-completion sets `somethingElseDone = true`
3. DoSomething-completion checks if both is true, which they are
4. DoSomethingElse-completion checks if both is true, which they are.

Can this happen? Can the main.asyc call happen "intertwined"?

Comment: No, because iOS multi tasking is not preemptive. The asynchronous closures can't be "interrupted", they need to relinquish the thread explicitly.

Comment: @Paulw11 is this documented somewhere? I'm having a hard time "imagining" how it can be like that. I mean, at any give time, if I call `DispatchQueue.main.async` from any thread, won't I be "interferring" with whatever the MainThread is currently doing in some way? What's stopping another main.async-call from "interferring" with both Main-operations and another main.async-operation? Does a main.async-call really hijack the entire UI-thread for the entire duration of the block, no matter what was currently happening in MainThread before - UNLESS it was another main.async-hijack? #confused

Comment: You are dispatching onto a *queue*; You are saying "do this *later*, after you have finished what you are doing and after anything else that is already in the queue".  iOS multi tasking doesn't have preemption. Blocks/closures are run atomically. This is why it is bad idea to perform intensive tasks on the main queue, as it then can't do the work required to update the UI. It isn't that you have taken the CPU away but rather that you aren't giving it back. You can read about Grand Central Dispatch and the main RunLoop.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! _Queue_ was the keyword for me to understand this:) I never really thought of the meaning of the word until you put it in italics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**:
NO. The `everythingDone` can't be called twice.

**Long answer**:
The main *queue* (`DispatchQueue.main`) is a **serial queue**, which means that tasks will be finished one by one, and the second `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure will **wait** until the first one finishes its job.

A little demonstration:
Imagine the following code:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Closure A
            for i in 0..<10 {
                print("a\(i)")
            }
        }
    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Closure B
            for i in 0..<10 {
                print("b\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
```

If you run this code, in the console you'll see the following result:

> a0
>   a1
>   a2
>   a3
>   a4
>   a5
>   a6
>   a7
>   a8
>   a9
>   b0
>   b1
>   b2
>   b3
>   b4
>   b5
>   b6
>   b7
>   b8
>   b9

As you can see, at first it runs and finishes the code inside `Close A`, and only after it starts and finishes the code inside `Closure B`.

But, if we modify our code a little bit (by moving closure directly to *global queue*:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //Closure A
        for i in 0..<10 {
            print("a\(i)")
        }
    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {   
        //Closure B         
        for i in 0..<10 {
            print("b\(i)")
        }
    }
```

The result will be the following:

> b0
>   a0
>   b1
>   b2
>   b3
>   b4
>   b5
>   a1
>   b6
>   a2
>   b7
>   a3
>   b8
>   a4
>   a5
>   a6
>   a7
>   a8
>   a9
>   b9

Here you can see that the order is broken and it is even unpredictable, and it may change on every execution.
This is because `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)` is **concurrent** queue, so tasks will be performed simultaneously and will be finished on unexpected schedules.

So as soon as your closures are in a serial queue (in your case it is main queue) then the answer is **NO**, otherwise, the answer is **YES**.